# sed Error "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, url, sed

Here is my program:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    message=( 'somewebsite1' 'somewebsite2' 'somewebsite3' 'somewebsite4' )
```

`for i in "${message[@]}"
do
longUrl=$(sed -ne 's/.*\(https\{0,1\}:\/\/[^"]*\).*/\1/p' "$i" | head -n 1)
if test "$longUrl"; then
    echo "Shortening Url $longUrl ..."
    shortUrl=$(curl -s https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{'longUrl': '$longUrl'}" | python -c 'import json, sys; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["id"])')
    message=${message/$longUrl/$shortUrl}
    printf "%s\n" "$i" >> file.txt
fi
done
</pre>`

I am trying to shorten the URL by putting all of them into an array, but after I run it, I get the following error:

sed: somewebsite1: No such file or directory
sed: somewebsite2: No such file or directory
sed: somewebsite3: No such file or directory
sed: somewebsite4: No such file or directory

Thanks!

Comment: sed is expecting a file as its input, not a string. your arguments are being interpreted as filenames, not as the actual text-to-be-processed.

Answer (score 1):

If you give `sed` an *[argument](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide#CommandsAndArguments)* it will treat it as a *path*. You need to give the input on [standard input](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput):

```
sed -e '...' <<< "$i"
```

Additionally, if you're new to shell programming you may want to post the resulting working script to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for tips.

Comment: Wow! That worked...however I end up getting the same URLs instead of a unique one for each entry: http://goo.gl/uf9Kk9 x 4